# How to load Json Array with php Curl or file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-curl

I'm trying to load Json array from this [URL](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%225651383153%22%2C%22first%22%3A12%2C%22after%22%3A%22AQBhK6NMtUNzknGmu0dzV4zvZKwNIE6mprZX4JjefbMTGew9S28LTS0dQ-lgfIHo9SIgLWl6_yYlfgUap6Ye_Lc9KxIfG53QOwKVIb1PZdkqcA%22%7D)

What I tried so far is following:

```
//By Using File_get_contents()

$insta_source = file_get_contents($url);
$insta_array = json_decode($insta_source, TRUE);    
var_dump($insta_array);

//AND
//By Using php CURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);

//As in output it gives "Bool(false)" (get_file_contents())
//Curl Error gives : "bool(true)" but not the json array
```

Many Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Did you read the error? *You don't have authorisation to view this page.*

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I updated my question, Please review.

Comment: I have even tried post request, its giving 403 error code. You can not do anything about it.

Comment: Please check my question again I updated. In CURL its giving me "Bool(true)" after adding additional parameters. Now the problem is we need that Json Array instead of Bool

Comment: add `$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` before `curl_close($ch);` and see what is the response code. Its a 403. You can not access that page.

Comment: But when I directly use that URL i got the data I guess there is some cookie need to have in header.

Comment: Yes, you need to supply the cookies. If you are using chrome/chromium then you can export them using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content of a cURL request, you have to use the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` setting, as mentioned on http://www.php.net/curl_exec:

> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, it will return the result on success, `FALSE` on failure.

So you just need to enable the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` setting.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```